# Bluetooth mouse stays connected only for 5 seconds

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth, wireless-mouse

My Bluetooth mouse, HP x4000b, has worked perfectly for 2 years, connecting it to my Windows 10 laptop.

Now, however, I can only make it connect to my PC computer for about 5 seconds after I turn the mouse off and on. In these 5 seconds, I can see that it is connected, but the computer doesn't recognize it's clicks and movement. It taking a little while for the computer to recognize the input from the mouse is, however, normal. I have tried opening it up and removing dust, switching batteries multiple times, checked for driver updates, turned off device battery saving, and restarted the computer with no effect. Furthermore, my Bluetooth headset connects and stays connected without issues, and I've tried to connect the mouse to another computer, but it suffers from the same issue.

From this I have concluded that the issue lie with the mouse itself. However, is it a hardware or a software issue? The "connecting-light" on the mouse works perfectly, and the computer is able recognize the mouse for a couple of seconds, which makes me think that there is nothing wrong with the mouse's power access nor Bluetooth components. Is this a reasonable conclusion? Do I have to buy a new mouse, or is there something else I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a hardware issue, because even though the mouse connects for a couple seconds you said it does not function at all.

Further proving that this is a hardware issue with your mouse is that fact that the mouse does not work on other computers.

You have tried pretty much all the possible solutions to fix your mouse, so most likely you will need to get a new mouse.